# Understanding derivative of matrices

Tags: matrices, derivatives, regression, linear-regression

I came across following:

> $$\nabla_w\lVert y-\phi w\lVert^2_2=-2\phi^\color{red}{T}(y-\phi w) $$
> where $\lVert x\lVert$ is L2 norm function or euclidean distance. All $\phi,w$ and $y$ are matrices. $\phi^T$ is transpose of $\phi$

**Doubt:**

I know how how $\nabla_w\lambda \lVert w\lVert^2_2=2\lambda w$. As somewhat explained in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e73033jZTCI) video. By similar logic, I was thinking that $\nabla_w\lVert y-\phi w\lVert^2_2=-2\phi(y-\phi w) $. But the text says $\phi^\color{red}{T}$. How that transpose appeared?

PS: I came across this while learning ridge regression.

Answer (score 1):

It must be $\phi^T$ otherwise the dimensions will not match. Consider the gradient of $x^TAx$ given by $Ax +A^Tx$ which reduces to the example you gave when $A$ is the identity.

Comment: Sorry to come back here again so late. Is it that the derivative can mathematically still be $-2\phi(y-\phi w)$, but since all $y$, $\phi$ and $w$ are $n\times 1$ vector, $(y-\phi w)$ is also $n\times 1$ vector and to make the product dimensions compatible, we simply take transpose of $\phi$ to get $-2\phi^T(y-\phi w)$ instead of just leaving it un-transposed?

Comment: That explanation makes sense to me

Answer (score 0):

Note that
\begin{eqnarray}
\left\Arrowvert y - \phi w\right\Arrowvert^2 &=& \left<y - \phi w,y - \phi w\right>,
\end{eqnarray}
where, for matrices, the inner product $\left<\cdot,\cdot\right>$ is the [Frobenius inner product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_inner_product): $\left<A,B\right> = \textsf{Tr}(A^{\textsf{T}}B)$.

Let's consider the derivative in the direction of $u$, which we assume has unit norm: $\left\Arrowvert u\right\Arrowvert = 1$.
\begin{eqnarray}
&& \frac{\left<y - \phi (w + \epsilon u),y - \phi (w + \epsilon u)\right> - \left<y - \phi w,y - \phi w\right>}{\left\Arrowvert\epsilon u\right\Arrowvert}\\
&=& \frac{\left<y - \phi (w + \epsilon u),y - \phi (w + \epsilon u)\right> - \left<y - \phi w,y - \phi w\right>}{\epsilon}.
\end{eqnarray}

The first term in the numerator can be expanded as follows.
\begin{eqnarray}
&& \left<y - \phi (w + \epsilon u),y - \phi (w +\epsilon u)\right>\\
&=& \left<y - \phi w,y - \phi w\right> - \left<y - \phi w, \epsilon \phi u\right> - \left<\epsilon\phi u,y - \phi w\right> + \left<\epsilon\phi  u,\epsilon\phi u\right>\\
&=& \left<y - \phi w,y - \phi w\right> - \epsilon\left<y - \phi w, \phi u\right> - \epsilon\left<\phi u,y - \phi w\right> +\epsilon^2\left\Arrowvert\phi\right\Arrowvert^2.
\end{eqnarray}

If all of the matrices are real, then
\begin{equation}
\left<y - \phi w, \phi u\right> = \left<\phi u,y - \phi w\right>.
\end{equation}
The divided difference is thus
\begin{eqnarray}
-\frac{2\epsilon\left<\phi u, y - \phi w\right> + \epsilon^2}{\epsilon}
&=& -2\left<\phi u, y - \phi w\right> + \epsilon\left\Arrowvert\phi\right\Arrowvert^2\\
&\to& -2\left<\phi u,y - \phi w\right>~~\textrm{as $\epsilon\to 0$}.
\end{eqnarray}

This shows that the *directional derivative in the direction of $u$* is
\begin{eqnarray}
-2\left<\phi u,y - \phi w\right> &=& -2\mathsf{Tr}\left((\phi u)^{\mathsf{T}}(y-\phi w)\right))\\
&=& -2\mathsf{Tr}\left(u^{\mathsf{T}}\phi^{\mathsf{T}}(y-\phi w)\right))\\
&=& -2\left<u,\phi^{\mathsf{T}}(y-\phi w)\right>.
\end{eqnarray}

Since we take the inner product of $u$ with $-2\phi^{\mathsf{T}}(y-\phi w)$ to get the directional derivative in the direction of $u$, $-2\phi^{\mathsf{T}}(y-\phi w)$ is the derivative.